# sqlserver - if a variable meet a requirement , it will trigger specific conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a `WHERE` clause that would trigger specific conditions if a variable meet specific requirements

```
 WHERE 
     CASE 
      WHEN @Restriction = '1' THEN CFE_EDI.ETAT = 'ENV' OR CFE_EDI.ETAT = 'OUV'
      WHEN @Restriction = '0' THEN CFE_EDI.ETAT <> 'ENV' AND CFE_EDI.ETAT <> 'OUV'
      ELSE CFE_EDI.ETAT != '' AND CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE IS NOT NULL 
     END
```

As you can see, it won't work as `CASE` does not work well with having conditions after the `THEN`

One solution , a friend of mine came up with , would be that

```
WHERE (@restriction = 1 AND CFE_EDI.ETAT IN ('ENV', 'OUV'))
OR (@restriction = 0 AND CFE_EDI.ETAT.ETAT NOT IN ('ENV', 'OUV'))
OR (CFE.EDI.ETAT <> '' AND CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE IS NOT NULL)
```

Yet, thinking about it, the logic would be if @Restriction is equal to one then put the conditions `CFE_EDI.ETAT = 'ENV' OR CFE_EDI.ETAT = 'OUV'` and the solution proposed by my friend does not do that.

I know it can be done in Crystal Reports but I'm unsure there is way of doing it in SQLServer.

Thanks

Comment: `Column IN (A,B)` is exactly the same as `Column = A OR Column = B`. It's not clear why you think your friend's solution doesn't fit the bill admirably.

Comment: Hi @Damien_The_Unbeliever I want if restriction= 1 then WHERE CFE_EDI.ETAT = 'ENV' OR CFE_EDI.ETAT = 'OUV'. If restriction = 1 then WHERE CFE_EDI.ETAT <> 'ENV' AND CFE_EDI.ETAT <> 'OUV'. Does it make sense?

Comment: What doesn't make sense at the moment is why you think your friend's solution doesn't work.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i'm not familiar in writing a query that manner, this is the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already your friend solution would work for your scenario but I don't why are you telling that it doesn't work. You can try this but it is similar to your friend solution.

```
WHERE ((@restriction = 1    AND (CFE_EDI.ETAT='ENV' OR CFE_EDI.ETAT='OUV'))
         OR (@restriction = 0   AND (CFE_EDI.ETAT<>'ENV' AND CFE_EDI.ETAT<>'OUV'))
         OR (CFE.EDI.ETAT <> '' AND CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE IS NOT NULL))
```

Comment: I guess I'm not used to it @stackuser. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use case in where condition

```
WHERE 
    CASE 
        WHEN @Restriction = '1' AND CFE_EDI.ETAT IN ('ENV', 'OUV') THEN 1
        WHEN @Restriction = '0' AND CFE_EDI.ETAT NOT IN ('ENV', 'OUV') THEN 1
        WHEN CFE_EDI.ETAT <> '' AND CFE_EDI.CODE_INSEE IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END = 1
```

Comment: Hi @eric what did you put a `END = 1`?

Comment: @AndyK The `CASE` statement will return a number 1 or 0, which is not a boolean expression, so there is a ` = 1` at the end.