# Select Records Expert equivalent for SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, crystal-reports

Crystal Reports has the Select Records Expert which allows you to use variables to build `WHERE` conditions. Is there something similar to the select records experts in SSRS?

If the variable @Restriction below is equal to one, the column name `CFE_EDI.ETAT = 'ENV' or CFE_EDI.ETAT = 'OUV'`. I tried to mimic the functionality with a [SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39386711/sqlserver-if-a-variable-meet-a-requirement-it-will-trigger-specific-conditio) but due to `AND` and `OR` precedence, the `WHERE` condition is not functioning properly.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you refer to parameters, check [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337432(v=sql.105).aspx) and [this one](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2012/1/8/relating-parameters-filters-in-sql-server-reporting-services.html)

Comment: Thanks @alejandrozuleta. This is not filter I'm after , it is more something similar to the selection records expert, which is a different ball game

Comment: SSRS or SQL does not easily allow you to change the `where` clause of the script based on parameters as you are able to do in Crystal Reports.  What you can do instead is use a `case` statement (The SQL equivalent of `if..then..else`) to find out if the data matches the required criteria and then filter based on the result of the `case` statement.  Whilst this doesn't change the `where` clause as per Crystal, it provides the same final output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this within the SQL of your SSRS Dataset `where` clause buy using `case` statements that return a `1` or a `0` depending on whether or not the criteria is met:

```
where case when @Restriction = '1'
              then case when CFE_EDI.ETAT in('ENV','OUV') then 1 else 0 end
           when @Restriction = '0'
              then case when CFE_EDI.ETAT not in('ENV','OUV') then 1 else 0 end
           else case when CFE_EDI.ETAT <> '' then 1 else 0 end
       end = 1
```

Comment: Hi @iamdave what means the `END= 1`

Comment: @AndyK  `case when...then...else...end` is the same as `if...then...else...end`.  The case statement here checks if the various elements of your data meet the requirements by following the logical process as it does in the `if` statement in your screenshot.  If you follow the process through you will see that it first checks if `@Restriction = 1`.  If it does it then checks whether the value in `CFE_EDI.ETAT` is in the list `'ENV','OUV'`.  If it is again, the result of the `case` statement is `1` and if not `0`.  So the `end = 1` is checking that the `case` statement returned `1` or `0`.

Comment: you just saved me from a massive headache